# How do I pass information from a database using PHP

Tags: php

I have a database holding customer details, I want to view all these details in a table. I want an edit button beside each name, encase the admin needs to update a user name for example. When the admin click edit say for example on "jessica" row they will be brought to another page which will display all of jessicas details and the admin can update these and save them to the database. So far on my first page I have this: Its the posting to the next page I am struggling with:

```
<?php


  // the preparation
  include ("dbConnect.php");

$query = $db->prepare("select * from customer");
$query->execute();

// Display search result
if (!$query->rowCount() == 0) {

    echo "<table id=\"example\" style=\"font-family:arial;color:#ffffff;\" class=\"table table-striped table-bordered\" style=\"width:100%\">"; 
    echo "<thead><tr>
    <th style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:3px;border-color:#575757;background:#575757;\">ID</th>
    <th style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:3px;border-color:#575757;background:#575757;\">Forename</th>                
    <th style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:3px;border-color:#575757;background:#575757;\">Surname</th>
    <th style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:3px;border-color:#575757;background:#575757;\">Telephone</th>
    <th style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:3px;border-color:#575757;background:#575757;\">Address</th>
    <th style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:3px;border-color:#575757;background:#575757;\">Medical Conditions</th>
    <th style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:3px;border-color:#575757;background:#575757;\">DOB</th>
    <th style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:3px;border-color:#575757;background:#575757;\">Email</th>
    <th style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:3px;border-color:#575757;background:#575757;\">Password</th>
    <th style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:3px;border-color:#575757;background:#575757;\">Last Login</th>
    <th style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:3px;border-color:#575757;background:#575757;\">Edit</th>
</tr></thead><tbody>";
$position = 1; 
while ($results = $query->fetch()) {


    $count = count($results);

    echo "<tr><td style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#D3D3D3;\">";            
    echo $results['id'];
    echo "</td><td style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#D3D3D3;\">";
    echo $results['forename'];
    echo "</td><td style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#D3D3D3;\">";
    echo $results['surname'];
    echo "</td><td style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#D3D3D3;\">";
    echo $results['telephone'];
    echo "</td><td style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#D3D3D3;\">";       
    echo $results['address'];
    echo "</td><td style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#D3D3D3;\">";           
    echo $results['medical_conditions'];
    echo "</td><td style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#D3D3D3;\">";           
    echo $results['dob'];
    echo "</td><td style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#D3D3D3;\">";       
    echo $results['email'];
    echo "</td><td style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#D3D3D3;\">";           
    echo $results['password'];
    echo "</td><td style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#D3D3D3;\">";           
    echo $results['last_login'];
    echo "</td><td style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#D3D3D3;\">";

    echo '<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Edit" href="editDetails.php">';
    //echo "</td><td style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#D3D3D3;\">";
    } 
}               

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $forename = $_POST['forename'];
    $surname = $_POST['surname'];
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $medical_conditions = $_POST['medical_conditions'];
    $dob = $_POST['dob'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $last_login = $_POST['last_login'];
    if($id !=''||$forename !=''||$surname !=''||$telephone !=''||$address !=''||$medical_conditions !=''||$dob !=''||$email !=''||$password !=''||$last_login !=''){}

    $query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO customer values (id, :forename, :surname, :telephone, :address, :medical_conditions, :dob, :email, :password, :last_login)");
    $dbParams = array('id'=>$id, 'forename'=>$forename, 'surname'=>$surname, 'telephone'=>$telephone, 'address'=>$address, 'medical_conditions'=>$medical_conditions, 'dob'=>$dob, 'password'=>$password, 'last_login'=>$last_login);
    $query->execute($dbParams);

}
?>
```

Comment: ___struggling with___ in exactly what way?

Comment: Submit buttons need a `name` attribute or they are not send to the PHP Script `<input type="submit" name="Submit"`

Comment: When you click the "edit" button the user is only redirecteed to "editDetails.php" but there are no data passed with. So you can't determine the selected user on this page.

Comment: You should use a link instead of submit button. `<a href="editDetails.php?id="<?php echo $results['id']; ?>" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>` Then use the GET id parameter to get the data on the edit page. There nothing that implies you even have a form on the page and a submit button posts a form.

Comment: Also when the button is clicked, the script stores some data to the database, but not the ones from the selected row, because no data is passed to the `$_POST` variable